# Action Script 3. Restore timer to 0 after game restart

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object, actionscript, timer

I'm creating flash game, here is timer which counts how long player playing at current level. And here is "Restart" button, I need to restart timer (count from 0) after this button is clicked.

Here is my timer's code:

```
 public function MemoryGame()
            {
                addChild(CardContainer);
                tryAgain.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, restartGame);
                    timer = new Timer(1000); //create a new timer that ticks every second.
                    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tick, false, 0, true); //listen for the timer tick

                    txtTime = new TextField();
                    addChild(txtTime);
                    tmpTime = timer.currentCount;
                    timer.start();
    }

            private function tick(e:Event):void {
               txtTime.text = showTimePassed(timer.currentCount - tmpTime);                 
                var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
                format.font = "Verdana";
                format.color = 0xFF0000;
                format.size = 16;
                format.bold = true;  
                //txtTime.x = 250;
                txtTime.width/2;

                var stageCenter_x:Number = stage.stageWidth/2;
                var stageCenter_y:Number = stage.stageHeight/2;

                var textCenter_x:Number = txtTime.width/2;
                var textCenter_y:Number = txtTime.height/2;

                txtTime.x = stageCenter_x - textCenter_x;

                txtTime.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
               txtTime.defaultTextFormat = format;

    }
    function showTimePassed(startTime:int):String {

      var leadingZeroMS:String = ""; //how many leading 0's to put in front of the miliseconds
      var leadingZeroS:String = ""; //how many leading 0's to put in front of the seconds
      var leadingZeroM:String = "";

      var time = getTimer() - startTime; //this gets the amount of miliseconds elapsed
      var miliseconds = (time % 1000); // modulus (%) gives you the remainder after dividing, 

      if (miliseconds < 10) { //if less than two digits, add a leading 0
        leadingZeroMS = "0";
      }

      var seconds = Math.floor((time / 1000) % 60); //this gets the amount of seconds

      if (seconds < 10) { //if seconds are less than two digits, add the leading zero
        leadingZeroS = "0";
      }

      var minutes = Math.floor((time / (60 * 1000) ) );
        if (minutes < 10) { //if seconds are less than two digits, add the leading zero
        leadingZeroM = "0";
      }
      //60 seconds times 1000 miliseocnds gets the minutes
      return leadingZeroM + minutes + ":" + leadingZeroS + seconds + "" + leadingZeroMS ;



    }
```

When I use: `removeChild(txtTime);` and later `addChild(txtTime);` timer not restarting just removing for the time, later adding again and continue time counting. How to restore timer to 0? Any ideas? Thank you very much.

**EDIT:**
**Timer must resets when restartGame() function is used.**

When I use this - nothing happens.

```
public function MemoryGame()
        {
            addChild(CardContainer);
            tryAgain.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, restartGame);
                timer = new Timer(1000); //create a new timer that ticks every second.
                timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tick, false, 0, true); //listen for the timer tick
                        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, resetTimer);
                txtTime = new TextField();
                addChild(txtTime);
                tmpTime = timer.currentCount;
                timer.start();
}

        function restartGame(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, resetTimer);
    }

        function resetTimer(event:TimerEvent):void{
            timer.reset();
            timer.start();
        }
```

When I use this - timer stops and continue counting, but not reseting.

```
        function restartGame(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        timer.reset();
        timer.start();
    }
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
timer.reset();
```

to reset it and then start it again with:

```
timer.start();
```

See [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#methodSummary) for more info

Comment: Thank you for answer, but when I use timer.play(); I got error: `1061: Call to a possibly undefined method play through a reference with static type flash.utils:Timer.` and timer.reset(); just stops timer, not refresh to "0".

Comment: sorry - meant timer.start(). and it should reset counter to zero; not sure why its not working for you

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work. timer.reset(); I don't knwo why, but work the same as stop, It not reseting timer, just stopping. and when I use timer.start(); It continue counting.

Comment: Heres a small test program. you'll see that it resets count to zero: var timer:Timer = new Timer(100, 5);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
timer.start();

function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
{
 trace(timer.currentCount);
 if (timer.currentCount==3)
 {
  timer.reset();
  timer.start();
 }
}

Comment: I updated my question with code how It looks for now. Maybe this line is wrong ` timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, resetTimer);` ? I don't know how to use resetTimer function correctly. If I use resetTimer(); I got error: `1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 1.`

Comment: resetTimer function looks fine in your code  - dont know why you have 3 addEventListeners though - you only need 1 of the ones in MemoryGame class

Comment: 1 I use for tick() function other for resetTimer(). But why timer after timer.reset(); not reseting, just stopping..?

Comment: i think part of the problem is multiple event listeners - you are adding 2 in MemoryGame() and adding another one each time restartGame() is run; and i dont see any removeListener calls.

Comment: Which one listener I need to use in MemoryGame() and when I need to remove listeners?